# Stop Animation of Sprites when touched in centre Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to stop all animations running on my `CCSprite` when the user touches a sprite in the sprite's center.

Can anyone help me come up with the code to do this or provide links to tutorials that might help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hadn't really asked a question there, I've edited your question. I think this should give you a good start.

Implement the CCTargetedTouchDelegateProtocol and focus on this method.

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(GCRectMake(/*Define a rect to represent the center of your sprite*/), [touch locationInView:/*View where you want the touch to be located, usually linked to the CCDirectors OpenGL view*/])
    {
        [sprite stopAllActions];
    }
}
```